# Moment generation function v.s. density function.

Tags: moment-generating-functions, density-function

I have a curiosity about the relationship between m.g.f. and p.d.f..

Actually, I knew like the following:
$$M_X(t)=E\left[e^{tX}\right]$$
where $M_X(t)$ is the moment generating function with respect to random variable $X$.

Also, I learned that m.g.f. is unique. So if m.g.f. of $X$ and $Y$ are same, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

However, my professor mentioned slightly that knowing all moments is equivalent to knowing density function.

Under any circumstances, is it possible to make a random variable's density function if I know its moment generating function?

I agree that if I have moment generating function which is well-known like Bernoulli, Poisson, ..., I can guess its density function.

However, I think it is not possible to make density function, even if I have a value of $E[X]$, $E[X^2]$, $E[X^3]$, and so on...

Is my thought wrong?

Comment: There do exist pairs of distributions that are not identical but that have identical finite moments of all orders.  And there are other distributions that are identical to any others that share the same moments. $\qquad$

Comment: See e.g. [Moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem).  You should also be aware that not every distribution  has all its moments, moments, and not every distribution that has a m.g.f. has a density.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think about these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m.g.f. $M(t) = E[e^{tX}]$, if it exists for $t$ in some real interval $-\epsilon < t < \epsilon$, also exists and is analytic for $-\epsilon < \text{Re}(t) < \epsilon$ in the complex plane.  In particular, the analytic continuation of the m.g.f. to imaginary $t$ is the characteristic function
$C(s) = E[e^{isX}]$.  We can then obtain the density, if indeed it exists, as the Fourier transform of the characteristic function.